# Interesting approach to Kepler problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I won't go into the explanation of this idea, because it is explained in this [blog post](https://johncarlosbaez.wordpress.com/2015/03/17/planets_in_the_4th_dimension/). In this [paper](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/mathematical/Goransson_Kepler.pdf), which was featured on John Baez's blog, $\frac {dt}{d\lambda}$ is given as $\frac r V$, where $\lambda$ is some parameter. John Baez, on the other hand, is working with single fixed energy $E$, so he chooses following units: $m=1$, $k=1$ and $E=-\frac 12$. $\frac {dt}{d\lambda}$ is defined as $r$.

I got the assignment to derive similar stuff that is derived in the blog post, and the definition for $\frac {dt}{d\lambda}$ is same as in Baez's blog post. Does this parametrization imply Baez's choice of units? It is stated in the assignment to start the derivation from the equation of motion.

Edit: I am confused again. So, Baez chose units, so that $V=1$? Single fixed energy means a single problem that gives the possibility of an easy calculation?

Comment: The equivalence of classes of integrable systems has been around for at least 30 or 40 years, or so. Specifically the equivalence of the Kepler problem to harmonic motion in 4 dimensions is well known, if not particularly well "advertised". As mentioned in the blog, the key in this case are so called Kustaanheimo-Stiefel transformations, which have been mentioned here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/what-is-a-kustaanheimo-stiefel-transformation. You can find plenty of literature on the subject that attacks this and similar problems in both classical mechanics and QM.

Comment: That was mentioned in Baez's post. My problem is much more mundane. I have the problem with choice of units.

Comment: It's not necessary for you to follow Baez's choices. You can leave m and E in your calculation, if you like. m is really just a scaling factor for the "speed of the movie". A test mass will orbit around a heavy central mass with a high velocity, while it would orbit a light central body in the same orbit slowly. That, of course, would also rescale the potential and kinetic energy in that same orbit. Beyond that m has physically no meaning. For fixed m, variable E will rescale the "size" of the orbits, so you can work on one scale by setting E=1 and still get all possible orbital shapes.

Comment: What is the function of $V$ in Göransson’s paper?

Comment: I understand the part with scaling and Baez's choice. But I maybe don't, because I have to prove that $\vec V$ lies on the sphere, but according to the paper, to have the sphere $V^2=1$ must be satisfied. This means that $E=-\frac m2$. Does that mean that definition of $m$ is ambiguous and that $E=-\frac m2$ gives different values for different definitions for $m$.